# Apache PDFBox, Boxable - HTML ordered/unordered list is incorrectly displayed

Tags: scala, pdfbox, boxable

I'm trying to create pdf file using apache pdfbox and dhorions/boxable library. However, I am having trouble displaying nested html list in the cells.

```
val document: PDDocument = new PDDocument()
var myPage: PDPage = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4)
document.addPage(myPage)
var yPosition: Float = 777
val margin = 40
val bottomMargin = 40
val yStartNewPage = myPage.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (margin)
val tableWidth = myPage.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin)
val table = new BaseTable(yPosition, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, document, myPage, true, true)
val row: be.quodlibet.boxable.Row[PDPage] = table.createRow(10f)
var cell = row.createCell((100 / 3f),"<ul><li>hello</li><li>hello 2</li><ol><li>nested</li><li>nested 2</li></ol></ul>", be.quodlibet.boxable.HorizontalAlignment.get("left"), be.quodlibet.boxable.VerticalAlignment.get("top"))
table.draw()
```

Output:

[image]

As, you can see in the image, list is not aligned properly, instead of tab in subchild, newline is displayed.

I'm using, boxable version 1.5-RC and pdfbox version 2.0.5.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want the ordered list nested in the "heelo 2" entry?

Comment: @mkl yes, I want ordered list as nested. However, I tried unordered list as well, but I get same error. btw, I have gone through github issues page of boxable, and found issues related to this as well which says this issues has been resolved in update, but I keep getting this error. I have gone through the updated codes and i think the updated codes is not merged with master. Do you have any solution?

Comment: If it's not yet merged with master, build your own jar from the respective development branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your observation with boxable version 1.5-RC which has been created Sat Jun 25 08:15:03 CEST 2016.

The current master branch contains a number of changes merged in after that date. And indeed, compiling it and using the resulting artifact with your code one gets a different image:

[image: Output with current master branch boxable]

Even though the master branch pom.xml still claims version 1.4 it appears to contain a number of fixes compared to 1.5-RC.

Thus, I would propose compiling the master code and using the resulting artifact. You should definitively update the version, though, e.g. to 1.5-SNAPSHOT or to 1.4.9 or something similar.

If for some reason you cannot do so, you might want to ask the boxable author for the release schedule.